# Result of a when chain in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, case

I have a chained `when` condition in a Spark DataFrame which looks something like this:

```py
df = df.withColumn("some_column", when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id1") & (df.some_qty != 0), df.some_qty)
                                 .when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id1") & (df.some_qty == 0) & (df.some_qty2 != 0), df.some_qty2)
                                 .when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id1") & (df.some_qty == 0) & (df.some_qty2 == 0), 0)
                                 .when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id2") & (df.some_qty3 != 0), df.some_qty3)
                                 .when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id2") & (df.some_qty3 == 0) & (df.some_qty4 != 0), df.some_qty4)
                                 .when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id2") & (df.some_qty3 == 0) & (df.some_qty4 == 0), 0))
```

In the expression, I'm trying to modify the value of a column based on the values of other columns. I wanted to understand the execution of the above statement. As in, are all the conditions checked for every row of the dataframe and if yes what happens when more than one `when` condition is true. Or is it the case the the order of chain is followed and the first one to be true is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every row is going to be checked. But spark takes care of optimizing that, so it's not like looping for each cell.

As for the order, with an exemple we can see that the first one is taken into account:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('id2','70.07','22.1','0','1'),
    ('id1','0','0','1','3'),
    ('id2','80.7','0','1','3'),
    ('id2','0','0','1','3'),
    ('id1','22.2','0','1','3')
    ],
    ['transaction_id','some_qty','some_qty2', 'some_qty3','some_qty4']
)\
    .withColumn('some_qty', F.col('some_qty').cast('double'))\
    .withColumn('some_qty2', F.col('some_qty2').cast('double'))\
    .withColumn('some_qty3', F.col('some_qty3').cast('double'))\
    .withColumn('some_qty4', F.col('some_qty4').cast('double'))\

from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lower, lit

df = df.withColumn("some_column",when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id1") & (df.some_qty != 0),lit('first_true'))
                                 .when((lower(df.transaction_id) == "id1") & (df.some_qty != 0),lit('second_true')))
df.show()

# +--------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
# |transaction_id|some_qty|some_qty2|some_qty3|some_qty4|some_column|
# +--------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
# |           id2|   70.07|     22.1|      0.0|      1.0|       null|
# |           id1|     0.0|      0.0|      1.0|      3.0|       null|
# |           id2|    80.7|      0.0|      1.0|      3.0|       null|
# |           id2|     0.0|      0.0|      1.0|      3.0|       null|
# |           id1|    22.2|      0.0|      1.0|      3.0| first_true|
# +--------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: I had a follow up question. In case of chained 'withColumn', are they executed sequentially or in parallel. Like if a later part of the 'withColumn' chain depends on a column modified in the earlier part of the chain?

Comment: They are sequential. ```withColumn``` "creates" a new dataframe with that column. Then you repeat the operation on that new dataframe and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a sample dataframe and check it. As can be seen,
*when both conditions are true, only the first returns the result.*

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2,), (2,), (0,)], ['col_1'])

df = df.withColumn("some_column", F.when(F.col('col_1') == 2, 'condition1')
                                   .when(F.col('col_1') > 1, 'condition2'))
df.show()
# +-----+-----------+
# |col_1|some_column|
# +-----+-----------+
# |    2| condition1|
# |    2| condition1|
# |    0|       null|
# +-----+-----------+
```

Since there's no `otherwise` clause, everything what is not caught by any `when` condition causes the column to return null.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above, the chained `.when` methods do need to evaluate correctly. The below gives an error, even though the second `when` isn't ever used:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('id2','70.07','22.1','0','1'),
    ('id1','0','0','1','3'),
    ('id2','80.7','0','1','3'),
    ('id2','0','0','1','3'),
    ('id1','22.2','0','1','3')
    ],
    ['transaction_id','some_qty','some_qty2', 'some_qty3','some_qty4']
)

df = df.withColumn("some_column", F.when(F.col('some_qty4') == 2, F.lit(1))
                                   .when(F.col('some_qty4') > 1, F.col('undefined_col')))
df.show()
```

This differs from python if...else logic where the following runs quite happily:

```py
if False:
    print(undefined_variable)
else:
    print("ok")
```